# Facebook Graph Search return proper JSON

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api, mechanize

I've been using mechanize lately to crawl around the web and do stuff.  I decided that I wanted to write some algorithms to graphically show connections between my friends.  Each friend will be a node within the graph, and if a node is friends w/ another node, there will be an edge between them.  Essentially just mutual friends functionality of facebook, but I want it in a node represented graph like a big spiderweb; the networkx library and matplotlib can achieve this.  Anyway, I've got a huge list of dictionaries with each of my friend's names and ids like so:

```
friends = [
    {
     "name": "friendA",
     "ID": "99999999999"
    },
    {
     "name": friendB",
     "ID": "66666666666"
    }
]
```

So I've been using mechanize's browser to go to the graph search page and do what I need:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
cj = cookielibLWPCookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0(X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.set_other_stuff(True)

# this will bring me to the Graph API, after I've logged in and stuff of course
# but for simplicity, we'll just assume I've already done that.
br.open("https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/")
```

After I've made it to the Graph API and gotten an access token, which I do, I can do the following.

```
# find our forms that we need to fill in with necessary information to get mutual friends

for form in br.forms():
    print form

1)
<GET https://developers.facebook.com/search application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<HiddenControl(path=) (readonly)>
<TextControl(selection=Search Facebook Developers)>
<SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
2)
<POST https://www.facebook.com/logout.php application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<HiddenControl(fb_dtsg=AQAudA2Y) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(ref=ds) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(h=AfeHIBr1AyKI-60f) (readonly)>
<SubmitControl(<None>=Log Out) (readonly)>>
3)
<GET https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<TextControl(access_token=Paste in an existing Access Token or click 'Get Access Token' to generate one)>
<IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>
<SubmitControl(<None>=Debug) (readonly)>>

4)
<GET https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<SelectControl(method=[, *GET, POST, DELETE])>
<TextControl(path=)>
<SubmitControl(<None>=Submit) (readonly)>>
5)
<GET https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<HiddenControl(<None>=) (readonly)>
<TextareaControl(<None>=Input FQL query, <Tab> to autocomplete)>
<SubmitControl(<None>=Submit) (readonly)>>
```

As you can see there are five forms, only two of which we need to populate with information.  We need to pass our access token to form 3, which is at index 2, and we need to pass our query to form 4, which is at index 3.  I've just generated an access token to use in another browser and copied it into python with a variable.  If you are unfamiliar with mechanize, I'm able to select forms with **br.select_form()**

```
# select form 3 at index 2 to give access token
br.select_form(nr=2)
# to make sure all we need is writable
br.set_all_readonly(False)
access_token_var = 'AAACEdEose0cBAJ1FwFMNE7eLe4CZBPrz3q1AuKEZBsGKuwosCh8sPpHFLkOz2fZBmCV5uohZBI4SOTvUH4ilQEiPJE5KmEF73EdfzCP26jz7RFc9Kguu'
br['access_token'] = access_token_var

# now select the form to give it a path with what we need, which is form 4 at index 3
br.select_form(nr=3)
br["path"] = "/my_user_id/mutualfriends/friends_user_id"
br.submit()
```

Now, everything works, the form selection, population, and even submission, except viewing the JSON.  When I try and parse the response the generated JSON, which is entirely visible as a JSON library in the browser, it isn't anywhere to be found in the html response.  The elements containing it are hidden.   In the browser I get this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
    "name": "some person",
    "ID": "3214564851"
    }
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
]
}
```

I JUST want the JSON response with the **mutual** friends from the path I gave Graph API.  It seems that making this data easily parsable would be their priority, considering said data is the whole purpose of the API.  Instead of being able to iteratively generate these path responses through the Graph API, I am currently stuck individually passing paths and exhaustively copying and pasting; which I'm not going to settle for.  I'm sure there is a way I'm missing to do this, I just haven't found it yet and would really appreciate the help!

**EDIT:**

**ANSWER**

I found the answer shortly thereafter....

The API I was looking for and finally found was:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/mutualfriends/friend_id?access_token=accessToken
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this by scraping Facebook's UI rather than simply hitting the API directly?

Comment: How would I, as you say, hit the API directly then?  Do you mean https://graph.facebook.com/somestuff?  I just touched facebook's Graph API for the first time yesterday.  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. Sorry I ran away right after I commented and didn't see your response until now. I see you've figured this out for yourself, so great!

Comment: The graphs looked cool :)

Comment: @MartinAtkins I figured you might enjoy this: [Blog on above](http://www.wesmadrigal.blogspot.com/#!http://wesmadrigal.blogspot.com/2013/04/graphing-facebook-friends-mutual.html)